# Select concat between colections by linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have Two collections, every collection is type of **Model Object** , **Type Object** , ** Version Object** and I need to get a list of **ConcateName Object** by linq, this object has concatination of 2 names of Type and Model and Version plus a list of details of every name(details in Classes section):

**Classes**

```
class Model
{
    public string name { get; set; } // Exemple: "M1"
    public string Id { get; set; }  // Exemple:  "codeM1"
}

class Type
{
    public string name { get; set; }  // Exemple: "T1"
    public string Id { get; set; }  // Exemple: "codeT1"
}

class Version
{
    public string name { get; set; } // Exemple: "V1"
    public string Id { get; set; }  // Exemple:  "codeV1"
}

class ConcateName
{
    public string ConcateName { get; set; } // exemple:  "M1 T1"
    public List<ConcateNameInfo> ConcateNameInfos { get; set; }
}

class ConcateNameInfo
{
    public Guid TechnicalId { get; set; }
    public string Criteria { get; set; }  "M1"
    public Guid ValueId { get; set; }  "CodeM1"
}
```

**List of Models**

```
var models = new List<Model>();
var model1 = new Model(){name ="M1", id= "CodeM1"};
var model2 = new Model(){name ="M2", id= "CodeM2"};
models.Add(model1);
models.Add(model2);
```

**List of Types**

```
var types = new List<Type>();
var type1 = new type(){name ="T1", id= "CodeT1"};
var type2 = new type(){name ="M2", id= "CodeT2"};
models.Add(type1);
models.Add(type2);
```

**List of Versions**

```
var versions = new List<Version>();
var version1 = new Version(){name ="V1", id= "CodeV1"};
var type2 = new Version(){name ="V2", id= "CodeV2"};
models.Add(type1);
models.Add(type2);
```

**The OUTPUT WILL 12 Objects of ConcateName**

```
        var ConcateName1 = new ConcateName()
{
    ConcateName = "M1 P1",
    ConcateNameInfos = new List<ConcateNameInfo>() {
                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                            TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                            Criteria = "M1",
                                                            ValueId = "codeM1"
                                                        },

                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                             TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                        Criteria    = "T1",
                                                        ValueId     = "codeT1"
                                                        }
    }
}

var ConcateName2 = new ConcateName()
{
    ConcateName = "M1 P2",
    ConcateNameInfos = new List<ConcateNameInfo>() {
                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                            TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                            Criteria = "M1",
                                                            ValueId = "codeM1"
                                                        },

                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                             TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                        Criteria    = "T2",
                                                        ValueId     = "codeT2"
                                                        }
    }
}

var ConcateName3 = new ConcateName()
{
    ConcateName = "M2 P1",
    ConcateNameInfos = new List<ConcateNameInfo>() {
                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                            TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                            Criteria = "M2",
                                                            ValueId = "codeM2"
                                                        },

                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                             TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                        Criteria    = "T1",
                                                        ValueId     = "codeT1"
                                                        }
    }
}


var ConcateName4 = new ConcateName()
{
    ConcateName = "M2 P2",
    ConcateNameInfos = new List<ConcateNameInfo>() {
                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                            TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                            Criteria = "M2",
                                                            ValueId = "codeM2"
                                                        },

                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                             TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                        Criteria    = "T2",
                                                        ValueId     = "codeT2"
                                                        }
    }
}




var ConcateName5 = new ConcateName()
{
    ConcateName = "M1 V1",
    ConcateNameInfos = new List<ConcateNameInfo>() {
                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                            TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                            Criteria = "M1",
                                                            ValueId = "codeM1"
                                                        },

                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                             TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                        Criteria    = "V1",
                                                        ValueId     = "codeV1"
                                                        }
    }
}

var ConcateName6 = new ConcateName()
{
    ConcateName = "M1 V2",
    ConcateNameInfos = new List<ConcateNameInfo>() {
                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                            TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                            Criteria = "M1",
                                                            ValueId = "codeM1"
                                                        },

                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                             TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                        Criteria    = "V2",
                                                        ValueId     = "codeV2"
                                                        }
    }
}

var ConcateName7 = new ConcateName()
{
    ConcateName = "M2 V1",
    ConcateNameInfos = new List<ConcateNameInfo>() {
                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                            TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                            Criteria = "M2",
                                                            ValueId = "codeM2"
                                                        },

                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                             TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                        Criteria    = "V1",
                                                        ValueId     = "codeV1"
                                                        }
    }
}


var ConcateName8 = new ConcateName()
{
    ConcateName = "M2 V2",
    ConcateNameInfos = new List<ConcateNameInfo>() {
                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                            TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                            Criteria = "M2",
                                                            ValueId = "codeM2"
                                                        },

                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                             TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                        Criteria    = "T2",
                                                        ValueId     = "codeV2"
                                                        }
    }
}


var ConcateName9 = new ConcateName()
{
    ConcateName = "T1 V1",
    ConcateNameInfos = new List<ConcateNameInfo>() {
                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                            TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                            Criteria = "T1",
                                                            ValueId = "codeT1"
                                                        },

                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                             TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                        Criteria    = "V1",
                                                        ValueId     = "codeV1"
                                                        }
    }
}

var ConcateName10 = new ConcateName()
{
    ConcateName = "T1 V2",
    ConcateNameInfos = new List<ConcateNameInfo>() {
                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                            TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                            Criteria = "T1",
                                                            ValueId = "codeT1"
                                                        },

                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                             TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                        Criteria    = "V2",
                                                        ValueId     = "codeV2"
                                                        }
    }
}

var ConcateName11 = new ConcateName()
{
    ConcateName = "T2 V1",
    ConcateNameInfos = new List<ConcateNameInfo>() {
                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                            TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                            Criteria = "T2",
                                                            ValueId = "codeT2"
                                                        },

                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                             TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                        Criteria    = "V1",
                                                        ValueId     = "codeV1"
                                                        }
    }
}


var ConcateName12 = new ConcateName()
{
    ConcateName = "T2 V2",
    ConcateNameInfos = new List<ConcateNameInfo>() {
                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                            TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                            Criteria = "T2",
                                                            ValueId = "codeT2"
                                                        },

                                                        new ConcateNameInfo
                                                        {
                                                             TechnicalId = Guid.newGuid(),
                                                        Criteria    = "T2",
                                                        ValueId     = "codeV2"
                                                        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = models.SelectMany(m => types.Select(t => new ConcateName
{
    ConcateName = m.Name + " " + t.Name,
    ConcateNameInfos = new List<ConcateNameInfo>
    {
        new ConcateNameInfo
        {
            TechnicalId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Criteria = m.Name,
            ValueId = m.Id
        },
        new ConcateNameInfo
        {
            TechnicalId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Criteria = t.Name,
            ValueId = t.Id
        }
    }
});
```

---

For an arbitrary number of classes, you would need to introduce an interface:

```
interface IHasNameAndId
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Id { get; }
}
```

Then you can calculate the Cartesian Product:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> enumerables)
{
    return enumerables.Aggregate
    (
        new [] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }.AsEnumerable(),
        (accumulator, enumerable) =>
            accumulator.SelectMany(x => enumerable.Select(x.Append))
    );
}
```

Which can be projected into your required structure:

```
var lists = new IHasNameAndId[] { models, types, //...
var output = lists
    .CartesianProduct()
    .Select(x => new ConcateName
    {
        ConcateName = string.Join(" ", x.Select(y => y.Name)),
        ConcateNameInfos = x.Select(y => new ConcateNameInfo
        {
            TechnicalId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Criteria = y.Name,
            ValueId = y.Id
        })
        .ToList()
    });
```

Comment: Hello @JohnathanBarclay thanks for your answer, what if we have 4 classes: Model, Type and two other classes, same as Model and Type

Comment: @Sacamoto I've expanded my answer.